# BASH - variable assignment via subshell and grep

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract a matched regex from this file:

```
abc
de

{my_pattern.global} # want to extract my_pattern.global
                    # without curly brackets
123
```

and assign it to a variable in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
l_config_file="my_file.cfg"
l_extracted_pattern=""
l_match_pattern="(?<={).+\.global(?=})"
l_my_dir=$(pwd)


echo "grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file"
echo "debug 1 - exit code: $?"

grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file
echo "debug 2 - exit code: $?"

sh -c "grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file"
echo "debug 3 - exit code: $?"

$l_extracted_pattern = "$(sh -c "grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file")"
echo "debug 4 - exit code: $?"

echo $l_extracted_pattern
```

Output:

```
grep -oP '(?<={).+\.global(?=})' /tmp/my_file.cfg
debug 1 - exit code: 0
debug 2 - exit code: 1
my_pattern.global
debug 3 - exit code: 0
./sto.sh: line 14: =: command not found.
debug 4 - exit code: 127
```

As you can see, the grep command works well (when executed via sh -c) but fails when trying to assign the output to the variable $l_extracted_pattern with exit code 127. That means the shell doesn't recognise the command. I suspect the regex is cause of the trouble here, but couldn't figure out what in particular. What's going wrong?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Even though I assigned it before already :

```
l_extracted_pattern=""
```

and tried to overwrite it later:

```
$l_extracted_pattern = "$(sh -c "grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file")"
```

That was a mistake. Apparently **no** variable assignment in bash may contain the $ before the variable name - even not when instantiated already before. Changed it to:

```
l_extracted_pattern = "$(sh -c "grep -oP '$l_match_pattern' $l_my_dir/$l_config_file")"
```

Comment: `foo = bar` is not an assignment in bash at all, even without the `$`; it runs `foo` *as a command*, with `=` as its first argument and `bar` as its second.

Comment: And the use of `sh -c` here is a very Bad Idea -- it introduces substantial  security concerns, as it allows your text to be evaluated as code.

Comment: What you need likely is `l_extracted_pattern="$(grep -oP "$l_match_pattern" "$l_my_dir/$l_config_file")"`. Notice the lack of space between the var name and the equal sign and the use of double-quotes around the variable referencing the pattern

Comment: @Aaron, why have `l_config_file` content expanded unquoted? More reliable to have `l_extracted_pattern="$(grep -oP "$l_match_pattern" "$l_my_dir/$l_config_file")"`